# Multimodule assembler program

Tags: assembly, dos, tasm, multi-module

I'm having troubles with creating simple multimodule program in DOS.

What I want is to create procedure which increments ax with 5 and call it from main procedure. But every time I start debugging I get strange problem with infinite one-instruction cycle:

```
add [bx:si], al
```

Down here is my first file:

```
;(tmp1.bat)
.model small
.386
extrn mytmp

.code
org 100h
start:
  mov ax, 5
  push ax
  call mytmp
  pop ax
  mov dl, al
  mov ah, 06h
  int 21h
  ret
end start
end
```

And the second file:

```
;(tmp2.bat)
.model small
.386
public mytmp

.code
mytmp: 
  pop ax
  add ax, 5
  push ax
  ret
END
```

What am I doing wrong?
P.S. compiling from DOS:

```
tasm tmp1.bat
tasm tmp2.bat
tlink /t tmp1.obj tmp2.obj
```

Comment: You are going to need to do some explaining about that " infinite one-instruction cycle": what (you think) it is, how do you know it is an infinite cycle, where on earth it is (I don't see it anywhere in the code) etc.  By the way, we would also be very curious to know what you mean with those "(tmp1.bat)" and "(tmp2.bat)" comments.

Comment: > "(tmp1.bat)" and "(tmp2.bat)" are those files names.
To say, I don't think that my code is exactly correct executing, as I want it to. So I'm asking you to tell about my mistakes ...

Comment: Sure. So, this has nothing to do with the correctness (or lack thereof) of your code, it is more of a convention type of thing, but you are likely to get in trouble if you do not do it right: assembly files have an `.asm` extension. The `.bat` extension is for batch files, which are entirely unrelated to assembly files.  Regarding your code not being correct, you still have not done anything about the main point of my first comment.

Comment: Here is some code from debug of .com that I get after linking: ... > mov ax, 0005 > push ax > call [010E] > add [bx + si], al > ...

I assume, the my code is linking incorrectly.

Comment: Well, in your code it says `mov ax` (which is nonsensical and it should be rejected by `tasm`) but your debugger says `mov ax, 0005`.  So, which one is it?

Comment: The second one :)
Bad code-pasting pratice ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TASM assembles `call mytmp` as an indirect call according to a value in `mytmp`. It doesn't know that `mytmp` is a procedure.

Change

```
extrn mytmp
```

to

```
extrn mytmp:PROC
```

Comment: yes, after painstakingly extracting all the necessary information from the OP one bit at a time, it turns out that this might in fact be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
pop ax
add ax, 5
push ax
ret
```

Is completely nonsensical and causes a crash.  You are popping the return address from the stack, adding 5 to it, putting it back in the stack, and returning.  So, the function returns to the original intended return address plus five, which is an arbitrary location five bytes after the location where the call was supposed to return.

Apparently, that's in the middle of some instruction, so the disassembler gets confused, and it is showing you that you are about to execute `add [bx:si], al` which is a nonsensical, non-existent instruction.

So, whatever it is that you thought you were trying to achieve with those 3 instructions in your `mytmp:` function, it is wrong, and you should not be doing it.

Comment: Well, that's not an issue, because return address is not at the top of the stack at this moment. Despite this, I deleted all the lines with stack usage and it's still executing the same way :(
Though, thanks for your researches :)

Comment: No, that *is precisely the issue*, because the return address is *always* at the top of the stack upon entry to a function.

Comment: Okey. Thanks you for this comment. But the problem is still actual.